# Make a Maintenance Page and activate

Tags: magento-enterprise, maintenance, magento-1.14

Where can I create a Maintenance Page and activate it in Magento Admin?
I'm using magento enterprise edition 1.14 version

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the magento store on Maintenance mode, you just need to create a file name `maintenance.flag` on the root.

The store will automatically go in maintenance mode. To modify the maintenance page you need to goto errors/default/503.phtml file and modify it as per your requirement.

To allow website access for certain ip address you can edit your index.php file as below and add you IP address in the allowed list seperated by comma.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = array('192.168.0.0');
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dexter! Is there a way for me to see the maintenance page without creating first maintenance.flag?

Comment: yes as i stated earlier goto->errors/default/503.phtml thats your maintenance page. You can edit the whole page as per your requirement. you can add your css and images too over there. There is a seperate folder for it in errors/default

Comment: I mean, can I see it on the web browser? what link should I use?

Comment: No you can't access this file directly... Htaccess wont let you.. moreover it would be a security breach too. The best thing is you make your maintenance page in local magento setup or create a static html with css and add it directly in 503.phtml

Comment: There is another way if you want... add the following code in your index.php `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = array('192.168.0.0');
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}` this will show maintanence page only to you

Comment: in the allowed list add your ip address..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17450/discussion-between-alyssa-reyes-and-dexter).